# VB Linq Group Join query FAILS to order the results in descending order

Tags: vb.net, linq

Has anyone got any clue why this query fails to order the results by descending `VisitStart` order, despite the two `OrderBy` clauses in the query?

The term "ΗμΏραΕπίσκεψης" is the "VisitStart" in Greeks!!

The two `OrderBy` clauses are placed because I desperately need to order the results by this `VisitStart` column in descending order!

Also, is it possible to replace the "null" result in the last column cells with either `0` (zero) or `""` (empty string)?

```
(From p In Patients
    Join v In Visits On v.Patient Equals  p 
    Join t In VisitTypes On v.VisitType Equals t
    Group Join m In Payments On m.Visit Equals v Into PaymentsGroup = Group, g = sum(Ctype(m.Ποσό, Integer?))
    Order By v.VisitStart Descending
    From pmnt In PaymentsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        Where 
        v.VisitStart.Year = 2017
        Select New  With {
        .VId = v.Id,
        .PId = v.PatientId,
        .Όνομα = p.Όνομα,
        .ΗμΏραΕπίσκεψης = v.VisitStart,
        .PtFirstVisitEver = p.Added,
        .Κόστος = v.Κόστος,
        .Πληρωμές = g
        }).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.ΗμΏραΕπίσκεψης).Distinct
```

Please find the corresponding image of the results here

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question rather than including it as a screen shot

Comment: @StevenDoggart Thanx for your prompt reply! I've made a few corrections to my question. I would appreciate if you could have a look at the new version. I apologize but I am very very new in here!! Thanx again!!

Comment: No problem.  It's a common newcomer mistake.  What is the type of the `VisitStart` property?  Does it matter if you put the `Distinct` first before the `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: VisitStart is DateTime and all the properties can be found at the left pane on the attached photo. I will have a go with your suggestion

Comment: I did put the distinct before the Orderbydesending but the resutls are even more confusing the order is totaly random. I wish I could send you the output as a photo

Comment: OMG!!! It worked!! I did something stupid minutes ago and it failed. Now it works like a charm by putting the Distinct before the OrderByDescending as you suggested!! <p> I can not get the last column null values to zero or empty strings though as yet. Any suggestion would be appreciated Also please guide me how to "congratulate" you for your help so far?

Comment: Thanx a million @StevenDoggart. Finally I got it to do what I wanted. Even the last column displays zeros now by putting .Πληρωμές = If(g Is Nothing, 0, g)

Comment: Yay.  I added it as an answer so you can mark it as the correct answer (once you're allowed to do so--I think there may be a time limit where you have to wait a half hour or something before you are able to mark the correct answer when you're a new user)

Comment: FYI, if all you need to do is return a default value if `g Is Nothing`, then you can just do `If(g, 0)`, which can be a bit easier to read, once you get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Distinct` method could alter the order of the list.  Therefore, if the order matters, you should do that last just to be safe.  In other words:

```
x.Distinct().OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.ΗμΏραΕπίσκεψης)
```

Instead of:

```
x.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.ΗμΏραΕπίσκεψης).Distinct()
```